# docker-compose drupal mysql SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, docker, drupal, docker-compose

I have tried all the solutions available on all forms but no success even tried using accepted answers docker-compose file but still getting the same error.

[image]

I am trying this on a freshly installed ubuntu 18 on VirtualBox. I have tried with all possible combinations of localhost, 127.0.0.1, changing user,  etc.

```
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:8
    container_name: drupal_container
    environment:
     DRUPAL_PROFILE: standard
     DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
     DRUPAL_USER: user
     DRUPAL_PASS: pass
     DRUPAL_DBURL: mysql://user:pass@database:3306/db
    #or mysql://user:pass@mysql_container:3306/db tried with both
    links:  
     - "mysql:mysql"
    depends_on:
     - mysql
    ports:
     - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - /var/www/html/modules
     - /var/www/html/profiles
     - /var/www/html/themes
     - /var/www/html/sites
    restart: always
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_container
    restart: always
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_DATABASE: db
     MYSQL_USER: user
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    expose:
     - 3306
```

I am able to connect MySQL via command line and the docker exec command

```
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -h127.0.0.1 -p3306 -uroot -proot
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -h127.0.0.1 -p3306 -uuser -ppass
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -hlocalhost -p3306 -uroot -proot
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -hlocalhost -p3306 -uuser -ppass
docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uroot -proot -e "Show databases;"
docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uuser -ppass -e "Show databases;"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it worked, not the way I expected but it did.

```
sudo docker inspect mysql_container
```

op->

```
"Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.22.0.2",
"IPPrefixLen": 16,
"IPv6Gateway": "",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
"DriverOpts": null
```

I tried with this IP add ie `"IPAddress": "172.22.0.2"`
drupal and below commands are able to connect

```
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -h172.22.0.2 -p3306 -uroot -proot
sudo mysql --protocol=TCP -h172.22.0.2 -p3306 -uuser -ppass
```

but still would like to know what is the significance of this IP address, how is this different from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and will this remain the same every time I pull the same image on different machines or it changs??

Answer (score 0):

I've attached the working compose file, you seem to be missing network through which the dockers should be connected.

Create the shared network for your containers

```
docker network create shared
```

```
version: '3.1'
networks:
  shared: 
    external:
      name: shared
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:8
    container_name: drupal_container
    environment:
     DRUPAL_PROFILE: standard
     DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
     DRUPAL_USER: user
     DRUPAL_PASS: pass
     DRUPAL_DBURL: mysql://user:pass@mysql:3306/db    # MySQL host should be same as service name created for mysql.
    #or mysql://user:pass@mysql_container:3306/db tried with both
    links:  
     - "mysql:mysql"
    depends_on:
     - mysql
    ports:
     - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
     - /var/www/html/modules
     - /var/www/html/profiles
     - /var/www/html/themes
     - /var/www/html/sites
    networks:
      - shared
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_container
    restart: always
    environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     MYSQL_DATABASE: db
     MYSQL_USER: user
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
     - 3306:3306
    expose:
     - 3306
    networks:
      - shared
```

When you try to setup the database in drupal use the following value for host, rest should be same as what you have been using.

> Host: mysql

Also, you could just change the 'DRUPAL_DBURL' value in your compose file. This way you are using the default network created by docker compose.

```
DRUPAL_DBURL: mysql://user:pass@mysql:3306/db
```